# the initialize computation to construct the server state

Tags: tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

In the federated learning context, and like this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification) shows, initial weights of global model (at server level) are initialized randomly with :  `state = iterative_process.initialize()`. I want to have the hand to put these initial weights by downloading them from another model (`load_model()`). So please how can I proceed, I'm newer in TFF.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can either manually create a state object with the same structure and any values you choose, or use [`tff.structure.update_struct`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/structure/update_struct).

If you already have a `my_model`, and instance of either `tff.learning.Model` or a `tf.keras.Model` with weights you want, you can write something like

`state = tff.structure.update_struct(state, model=tff.learning.ModelWeights.from_model(my_model))`